# Backbone.js with XML response - parse function not called before parse error

Tags: xml, ajax, parsing, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js to structure an application that usually communicates with web services via JSON.

One web service will return JSON on success or XML in an error (clever, huh?). I need to parse this XML response to determine the error, but Backbone's JSON-centric thinking is causing me problems.

I have a collection that includes a parse function. The parse function is always called when the service returns JSON, and in this case I simply return the response object. However, when the service returns XML my fetch call's error callback function is called, and passed an error object with `arguments[1]` of `parseerror`. Further digging shows there was an unexpected `<` character.

Why is my parse function not being called to parse the XML before a parseerror is thrown? Furthermore - why, in the successful JSON calls, is it passed a JavaScript object (indicating that the JSON string has already been parsed)? Isn't the parse function supposed to do the parsing?

Relevant code below, any suggestions much appreciated.

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

initialize : function() {
    ...
},

fetch: function(options) {

    var options = {data: {...}, error: this.onFetchError};

    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
},

onFetchError: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    debugger
},

parse: function(response) {

    debugger
    if(typeof response === 'object') {
        return response;
    }
}
});

return myCollection;
```

Comment: The parseerror is probably coming from jQuery or the XMLHttpRequest, not from backbone. Is the response being returned with an appropriate Content-Type, such as `application/xml`? And is the returned XML well-formed?

Comment: @breischl Thanks for the input, everything looks good on that side - Content-Type is `application/xml` and http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp told me the XML was well-formed

Comment: Is it possible that someone, somewhere is setting the jQuery `dataType` option on the request? Possibly it's being done in a `$.ajaxSetup()` or `$.ajaxStart()` call? If that's not it, I guess try setting breakpoints in the Backbone `success` and `error` functions and see if that yields more information.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation is vague about this.  `Model.fetch([options])` uses `Backbone.sync`.  The [docs for sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) say that you can use "all other jQuery request options", meaning anything supported by [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

So to get the response as raw text, you could do:

`this.fetch({ dataType: 'text' });`

Then in your `parse` function, you can deal with the response however you want.

Side note: I figured this out when trying to get a model to fetch XML, and tested with that dataType.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the default fetch:

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {

    //-->parse only invoked on success     
    if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, xhr), options)) return false;
    if (success) success(model, resp);
  };

  //-->parse not invoked on error
  options.error = Backbone.wrapError(options.error, model, options);
  return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
}
```

You see that parse will never get called on an error condition. However, wrapError (shown below) will give you the original response:

```
Backbone.wrapError = function(onError, originalModel, options) {
  return function(model, resp) {
    resp = model === originalModel ? resp : model;
    if (onError) {
      onError(originalModel, resp, options);
    } else {
      originalModel.trigger('error', originalModel, resp, options);
    }
  };
};
```

So your arg2 will have the response and conceivably, you could pass that to your parse function.